# how to write a trigger to stack up two columns from two different tables in sql

Tags: sql, triggers

We have three tables:

1.`CourseRequest` with fields `Request_id`,  `ExecutionStartingDate`, `ExecutionEndDate`.

2.`Courselist` with fields `list_id` ,`Request_id` ,`Planning_id`

3.`CoursePlanning` with fields `Planning_Id` and `CourseLength`.

Image of table structure:

[image]

I want for each time data inserted the ExecutionEndDate will be computed from ExecutionStartingDate + length and consider that the datatypes are datatime2 and int respectively with trigger.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (A very few dbms products have ANSI SQL compliant triggers, most of them have their own versions.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do the below:

1. Create a trigger for insert
2. Compute and update the executionEndDate field as required - for the update, you will need to join all 3 tables to find the related mapping.

Something like the below query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CourseRequest ON dbo.CourseRequest --Create insert trigger for table
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN

    --Get the newly inserted CourseRequest ID
    DECLARE @COURSE_REQ_ID INT
    SET @COURSE_REQ_ID = (SELECT Request_id FROM INSERTED)T

    UPDATE  CR --Update the details
    SET     CR = DATEADD(CR.EXECUTIONSTARTINGDATE,CP.LENGTH)
    FROM    CourseRequest CR
            INNER JOIN COURSELIST CL
            ON CR.REQUEST_ID = CL.REQUEST_ID
            INNER JOIN COURSEPLANNING CP
            ON CP.PLANNING_ID = CL.PLANNING_ID
    WHERE
            CR.REQUEST_ID = @COURSE_REQ_ID

END
```

I haven't compiled this in SQL server so there might be some syntax errors!